# how can I create 3d model of a tube clip which is mathematically correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm willing to 3d print a tube clip. In the photo is a simplified figure . The only thing that I know is the diameter of the tube that will enter in the tube-clip.

1. is there relation between diameter and x ?
2. is there relation between diameter and z ?
3. how will the length y affect the strength of holding the tube ?
4. what is the appropriate value of y so the tube clip doesn't break ?

[image]

Comment: I've flagged this question to be moved to the Mathematics Stack Exchange section. I believe it would be better suited there than in the Mechanics section. That being said, I will comment on a few things: The longer Y is, the stronger the clip will be, but the appropriate value of Y depends on how strong you want the clip to be and the material it is made out of. Also, x is related to the diameter AND z. You would need the diameter and z to calculate x and you'd need x and the diameter to calculate z. I'll leave the actual formula to someone on Math.SE.

Comment: ok that should work too. It's question that is about 3d printing, 3d modelling, mechanical forces, physics ... I didn't know where to put it exactly. so should I repost the question in mathematics section or that will be done automatically ?

Comment: Someone will come along and migrate it. I don't have the authority. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment it actually clarfied more the issue for me.

Comment: You may also think about fleshing the question out a bit more. I'm not even sure what the heck you're talking about, other than your willingness to do the 3d printing part.

Comment: @Paulster2 sorry for that ...I'm not good in explaining things and my english isn't good neither. My question is about how can I draw a functional tube-clip. Tube-clip that is plastic, a bit flexible and hold tight the tube. I wanted also to find general information about this coumpound but all what I found is 100 commercial versions for sale with no details about strength, deformation and dimensions. I wanted at least to find a design guide for tube-clips like those for drawing bolts and stuff. Anyways, comments and and answers helped a lot and I'm thinking of making a simulation on catia.

Comment: @Zodiac - It seems your English is just fine. I think I understand now what you are looking to do, though I definitely think Mathematics.SE was definitely a better choice to ask the question. As far as the clip goes, you also need to consider how far past centerline the clip will extend (when looking at your image, it would be from the center of the diameter towards the right). If I understand what you are trying to do, if it's too long, you won't get the clip onto the tube without it over flexing ... yet too short and it won't hold.

Comment: you are right and that's why the simulation is probably good solution. x and z are related to each other , so all what I have to do is to find the convenient x and y.

Answer (score 2):

To answer questions 1 and 2, there is a relationship between $x$, $z$, and the diameter. The relationship is

$$x=2\sqrt{r^2-(z-r)^2}$$

where $r$ is the radius, half the diameter. You can solve for $z$, if you would prefer to go the other way, but your choice of $z$ (which must be greater than $r$) will determine the gap space you call $x$.

To answer questions 3 and 4, The strength of the clip will be determined partly by the length of $y$. The longer $y$ is, the stronger the clip. How large $y$ needs to be is something you'll have to determine based on what you'll be using the clip for and the material using to build it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The formula seems correct. The rest is ok too... The material I want to use is plastic (plastic used in 3d printing). After reading the comments and answers I know for sure that y and and material type are the most important than x (x and z are related so focusing on one of them is enough).
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1,2

Geometry

$$ R= D/2 $$

$$ z = R ( 1+ \cos \alpha ) $$

$$ x = 2 R \sin \alpha $$

Questions 3,4

Mechanics of Materials

Do you want to load test after 3d printing? You should give tube material, diameter, thickness, dimension y,how the force is to be applied, strength/ modulus of material to be used for clamp, the remainder of horizontal dimension $h$ in block etc.

Tensile, compressive stresses can be evaluated first  using direct statics. We find bending and direct stresses, next superimpose them. The design is not mentioned in math site. Recommended to go to mechanical engg SE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I explained further the problem in the comments. As you said there are tests after 3d printing but I have to conceive a 3d model that solves as many issues as possible (over bending, blocking the tube from entering...).
The formula seems correct and simple. I'm looking for the formula used in the commercial versions of pipe-clip or tube-clip. I looked for that and I didn't find anything. 
Maybe I will re-ask the question later in an other section as you recommended.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually in your formula  x should be x = 2 R sinα.